# Run Java applet from web on local

Tags: jar

How can I run Java applet from web on local (Windows 7)?

I downloaded file A.jar.pack.gz from web. This file I unpacked by `unpack200.exe` and after running unpacking jar there is this: Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile C:\...

Comment: what is the command you are using to run that jar file

Comment: In command line by `java -jar "C:\..."` and normally in windows explorer by double click on file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have installed the jdk then
You can extract the jar file through the following command :

step 1: jar xvf jarfilename

and then

step 2: create any text or html file and make the following entry:

```
    <applet code="className" archive="jarname" height="any number" width="anynumber">
    </applet>
```

the classname can be found when you have extracted the jar through the step 1

step 3: appletviewer filename

and yes ofcourse for the above commands to work you must set the path till jdk\bin

Answer (score 0):

If a java program is written to be an applet, it will assume that it has all the support structure of an external applet player, browser, etc. It therefore generally won't be able to run on its own as a Java program.

Vijay's solution could work, as might opening your new HTML snippet in a browser. The only way to get it to run with nothing but Java would be to rewrite bits of the program to provide a stand alone interface, or contact the original developers asking whether they'd be willing to do so.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I guess "rewrite bits of the program to provide a stand alone interface" is not only manually rewrite some first bits.

Comment: Unfortunately not. It's the kind of rewrite that you'd need access to the original source code for, though if you had that it probably wouldn't be that hard to change.